# Range output into strings | Error: [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x02229CA0>]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate the numbers from 1 to 99 with range(100), but each output is a string. Example: ('1','2','3',...).

I already tried this solution but I get this error.

```
NUMBERS = (str(i) for i in range(100))

Error: [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x02229CA0>]
```

Thks

Comment: `NUMBERS = tuple(str(i) for i in range(100))`

Comment: This is not an error message. It's what a generator looks like when printed out.

Comment: @Julien - that code starts off at 0 instead of 1

Answer (score 1):

A comprehension surrounded by parentheses gives a lazy generator. Use square brackets if you want a list:

```
numbers = [str(i) for i in range(100)]
```

Alternatively turn the lazy generator into a tuple:

```
numbers = tuple(str(i) for i in range(100))
```

Comment: Or if they just want to iterate over them for printing, `for x in NUMBERS:`. Or you can unpack the generator expression as `print` arguments, `print(*NUMBERS)` (implicitly prints with space separation).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results to be in a tuple, you must write `NUMBER = tuple(...)`. (Alternatively, you can use `list(...for...)` or `[...for...]` to produce a list.)

Without `tuple`, the `(str(i) for i in range(100))` alone is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `range(start, stop, step)` function.
This is the output -

```
>>> nums = tuple(str(i) for i in range(1,100,1))
>>> nums
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99')
```